# SASS: Get value of existing background string and add to it?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I'd like to additively build backgrounds in SASS/Compass, ignorant of the existing background string.  I am able to accomplish by writing to a global var, but it seems sloppy.

Pseudo:

```
=mixin-add-icon
  // add a background icon
=mixin-add-gradient-from-color($color: blue !default)
  // add a background gradient
=mixin-add-texture-bg
  // add a bg texture

a
  background: blue
  +mixin-add-texture-bg
     // this should take the existing bg and add texture to it
  &.selected
    +mixin-add-gradient-from-color()
    +mixin-add-icon
       // these two should take the existing bgs strings from <a> and add to them
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to access an object's properties via Sass, but Sass is an open project so you can always go and ask the developpers if such a feature would be possible on their [Github repo](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues).